# Worklight : how to set use addGlobalHeader for WL.Client.invokeProcedure calls

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

For WorkLight applications I don't see some cookie headers being sent to the server for basic WL.Client.invokeProcedure calls.  How do you properly add cookie headers?  Ideally, these would be global but I read that there may be issues using  WL.Client.addGlobalHeader("Cookie"). procedure).

This is basically the code in Javascript:

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : "data",
    procedure : procedure,
    headers : { "Cookie", "CookieData=val" }
    parameters : parms,
};
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData)
```

Edited:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21678099
"The WL.Client.addGlobalHeader API replaces the entire 'Cookie' header and destroys the session state."

Comment: Can you elaborate on the statement of "issues"?

Comment: Did you try inspecting the network traffic using Wireshark to see if the cookie is indeed sent with your request?

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no way to add your own cookies to Worklight requests. Like your edit says, any Cookie header added using addGlobalHeader() gets replaced with only the cookies WL adds.

A feature request has been opened to see if this functionality could be added in future versions.

Comment: They are sent with the desktop browser version, if you use document.cookie.   Tested with a chrome browser.

Comment: Yes, because the implementation for how the cookies are generated varies with the OS they are run on; in the case of running it in a browser, not much is done, since it is not a production environment; but if you run it on any mobile device, it will likely be replaced.

Comment: I wonder if the native cookie manager functionality is available.  E.g. with the Java/Android code above, can we set the cookies.  Also, do you know any IBM documentation on this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that the tech note says that document.cookie should work, but I think this tech note is wrong; it will work in browsers, but not with devices due to the way Worklight is implemented at the moment.

Comment: At least the cookies are saved, e.g. if you look at the cookie stores on the devices.  Maybe not sent.

Answer (score 0):

MFP 7.0.0 added a new API - [`WL.Client.setCookie()`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html?lang=en-us#setCookie).

A usage example:

```javascript
WL.Client.setCookie({
  name: 'cookieName',
  value: 'cookieValue',
  domain: 'google.com',
  path: '/', // all paths
  expires: 0 // never expires
}).then(function() {
  // callbacks go here
});
```